# Define size of 2 dimensional array by parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters, dimension

I want to define some this:

```
int m=5;

int [,] matrix=new int[4,m];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: have you tried it yet? You would get the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you have works for fixed sized.  If you want a dynamic matrix then use something like

```
var matrix = new List<List<int>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have constructed array name is matrix and has dimension 3*3. You can change this code as your requirement.

```
int m=3
int [,] matrix = int [3,m] = {  
{0, 1, 2, 3} ,   
{4, 5, 6, 7} ,  
{8, 9, 10  }   
 };
```